# Catch Exception Strategy

Tags: mule

My Mule studio version is:
version: 3.4.0
buildDate: 201305141336

I am confused on the catch exception strategy... and maybe I need to use a different strategy. Basically I need to write data to a file. After the file write I want to send an email to indicate whether the write was successful or not. (Failure is most likely to happen if someone has the file open at write time). I originally tried putting an email in the catch exception block but what happened then was that I got both emails; the one in the catch block and the one at the end of the flow. I attempted to create a variable with the email subject in it and change the value out in the exception but it doesn't seem to do anything. I still get the email with the success message in it.

Does anyone have some suggestions on how to make this work? Ultimately, I just want to send a different email based on the file write success/failure. Here is my configuration. I have been causing the failure by opening the target file with Excel which locks the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:smtp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp" xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/smtp/current/mule-smtp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <flow name="FileOpenExample" doc:name="FileOpenExample" >
<quartz:inbound-endpoint xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" jobName="fileOpenEx" cronExpression="0,30 * * ? * FRI" repeatInterval="0" repeatCount="2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <set-payload value="Some Sample File Data" doc:name="Set File Data"/>
        <set-variable variableName="emailSubject" value="File Save Successful" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Temp\IntegrationTesting" outputPattern="Attributes.csv" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <set-payload value="This email was generated by a Mule process." doc:name="Set Email Body"/>
            <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail1.newpig.com" to="${email.toList}" subject="#[emailSubject]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="EmailSuccess"  />
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy" enableNotifications="false">
            <expression-transformer expression="#[emailSubject='Save Failed']" doc:name="Expression"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This scenario seems to be more similar like an earlier post.

Here the flow is posting onto an out-bound and then continue with the flow, as the out-bound is an asynchronous in nature. There needs to be something which can make the flow wait and then based on the status proceed further.

You can find the earlier similar post and my answer at the following link.

[Mule flow execution unexpectedly splits on error in SMTP sendout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821298/mule-flow-execution-unexpectedly-splits-on-error-in-smtp-sendout/16821698#16821698)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. That post put me on the right track. I have other issues with the process but that is for another post.